# Is it wrong to use 'but' and 'though' in the same sentence?

Tags: word-choice, semantics

I was talking to a friend of mine when I asked

> Where can I find that in our book? I did some search but I couldn't find it though.

That sounded a bit strange to me but I really don't know if I'm being redundant saying *but* and *though* in the same sentence.

Comment: Yes, "but ... though" is redundant in that context. *But though* it's redundant here, it's not always redundant.

Comment: Lawrence has it. The problem is not 'the same sentence,' but using both words to apply to the same clause, "X I couldn't find it X." Similar mistake: "though I couldn't find it however."